# How to set JTextArea size?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, joptionpane

I want to set a fixed size for `JtextArea` within `JOptionPane`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        JTextArea headersTxt = new JTextArea();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 50 ; i ++ ) {
            headersTxt.append("test \n") ;
        }
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(headersTxt); 
        scroll.setSize (300,600) ;  // this line silently ignored
        int test = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,  scroll,"test",  JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION) ;

    }
```

However, the above code ignores `scroll.setSize (300,600) ;`

It works fine but the size is not fixed  .  What is the problem with `scroll.setSize (300,600) ;` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because each system can render fonts differently, you should avoid using pixel measurements where possible

Instead, provide the rows and columns you want to display

```
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(5, 20);
```

Comment: Thank you . That works perfect !  I will avoid pixels where possible

Comment: Adjusting the **font size** of of a text area with columns and rows specified will also change the size of the text area.  See also [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)  That Q&A does not explicitly mention avoiding `setSize(..)`, probably because the size of a component is usually *ignored* by the layout manager, which will more commonly set a size based upon the preferred, maximum and minimum size.